# Gta5 Online Transfer from Xbox to Ps3

Tags: xbox-360, ps3, grand-theft-auto-online

My xbox profile for gta5 does not work is there anyway i could use my gta5 account on ps3.

Answer (score 0):

No. You can not transfer characters between platforms in GTA Online.